# How can I declare an array whose length is specified at runtime?

Tags: delphi

i need to declare an array with user-defined dimension. This array is inside a pretty big program and change to a list can be pretty a problem.

Now my array is declared like this:

```
Buffer: array[0..myCostant * 2] of Byte;
```

and `myCostant` is, like it says, an already defined constant.
Now i need to use a variable, getting something like this:

```
Buffer: array[0..myVar * 2] of Byte;
```

but i can't use variables inside array definition.

How i can solve this without changing my array in something else?
This variable is upper-bounded so can i declare array with this max size and reduce it with another instruction?

Comment: The documentation on arrays tells you all there is to know about arrays: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Arrays

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays):

```
var
  Buffer: array of Byte;

begin
  SetLength(Buffer, myVar*2 + 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use a static array of the known upper-bound length and record the current 'meaningful' length of the array in a variable, say `CurrentLength`.

Then you can replace, for instance,

```
for i := 0 to Length(Buffer) - 1 do
  SomethingWith(Buffer[i]);
```

by

```
for i := 0 to CurrentLength - 1 do
  SomethingWith(Buffer[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ISO standardized [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal)**:
If you are using a processor compliant with ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”, you can declare `array` avariables with *variable* sub‑range bounds just like that:

```pascal
    procedure someRoutine(n: integer);
        var
            { This `array` has a dynamic capacity of `n`. }
            foo: array[1..n] of integer;
        begin
        end;
```

To make your code work, the *value of* the variable just needs to *originate* from *outside* the scope you are currently declaring your `array` in.

> […] This variable is upper-bounded so can i declare array with this max size and reduce it with another instruction?

No, this is not how declarations work.
The processor guarantees that once the `begin`…`end` frame is entered, all  declarations within that block are and remain valid until (and including) the last statement prior the `end` is processed.
It is not possible to programmatically “invalidate” or partially “revoke” declarations.